# How to put same item in multiple groups inside ListBox

Tags: wpf

I would like to display a grouped ListBox like this :

- Tag A

  - Post 1
  - Post 2
- Tag B

  - Post 2

Source collection is a list of Post, each post can have many Tags.
If user selects "Post 2", it get highlighted twice.

I tried using an ICollectionView, but it need a Single value to filter, not multivalued one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this is your structure...

```
public class Post
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
}
```

The only way you can achieve tags based grouping is by flattening it out

```
var PostTagList = myPosts.SelectMany(
                 p => p.Tags,
                      (owner, tag) => new {owner, tag}).Select(
                         ot => new Post() 
                         {
                             Name = ot.owner.Name,
                             Tags = new string[] { ot.tag }
                         }).ToList();
```

This way you will have a flatten hierarchy of repeating `Post` objects with each of their Tags (i.e. `Post.Tags` property will have only one individual Tag for that `Post`).

After this, the grouping will apply just fine.